# strstr alternative for using older versions of php

Tags: php, strstr

I have a function that works in PHP v 5.3 and above but wondering what is the best method for doing this with a version below 5.3. My PHP version is 5.2.17

Here is my function for PHP v5.3

```
if (strstr($file2, '.', true) == strstr($file, '.', true)){
    $imagename = $file2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
if (strstr($file2, '.', true) == strstr($file, '.', true)){
```

I used the following and it works

```
if (substr($file2,0,strpos($file2,'.')) == substr($file,0,strpos($file,'.'))){
```

Answer (score 0):

From the manual comments, you could find this:

```
function rstrstr($haystack,$needle, $start=0) {
   return substr($haystack, $start,strpos($haystack, $needle));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642685/strstr-php-or-alternative-part-string) with this subject and the solution they found is to create your own strstr function which can be used also in old versions of php.

```
function my_strstr($haystack, $needle, $before_needle = false) { 
    if (!$before_needle) return strstr($haystack, $needle); 
    else return substr($haystack, 0, strpos($haystack, $needle)); 
}
```